# HMAC-SHA1: How to do it properly in Java?

Tags: java, hash, sha1, hmac

I'm hashing some values using HMAC-SHA1, using the following code in Java:

```
public static String hmacSha1(String value, String key) {
    try {
        // Get an hmac_sha1 key from the raw key bytes
        byte[] keyBytes = key.getBytes();           
        SecretKeySpec signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "HmacSHA1");

        // Get an hmac_sha1 Mac instance and initialize with the signing key
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
        mac.init(signingKey);

        // Compute the hmac on input data bytes
        byte[] rawHmac = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());

        // Convert raw bytes to Hex
        byte[] hexBytes = new Hex().encode(rawHmac);

        //  Covert array of Hex bytes to a String
        return new String(hexBytes, "UTF-8");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

`Hex()` belongs to `org.apache.commons.codec`

In PHP there's a similar function `hash_hmac(algorithm, data, key)` that I use to compare the values returned by my Java implementation.

So the first try is:

```
hash_hmac("sha1", "helloworld", "mykey") // PHP
```

that returns: `74ae5a4a3d9996d5918defc2c3d475471bbf59ac`

My Java function returns `74ae5a4a3d9996d5918defc2c3d475471bbf59ac` as well.

Ok, it seems working. Then I try to use a more complex key:

```
hash_hmac("sha1", "helloworld", "PRIE7$oG2uS-Yf17kEnUEpi5hvW/#AFo") // PHP
```

that returns: `e98bcc5c5be6f11dc582ae55f520d1ec4ae29f7a`

While this time my Java impl returns: `c19fccf57c613f1868dd22d586f9571cf6412cd0`

The hash returned by my PHP code is not equal to the value returned by my Java function, and I can't find out why.

Any tips?

Comment: Wouldn't it interpret $ chars in PHP as variable?

Comment: Why do you need the hex phase?

Comment: I have kind of same issue and unable to resolve it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971203/how-to-compute-hmac-on-the-bases-of-payload-and-secret-key

Answer (score 52, accepted):

On your PHP side, use single-quotes around the key so that the `$` character is not treated as a variable reference. i.e.,

```
hash_hmac("sha1", "helloworld", 'PRIE7$oG2uS-Yf17kEnUEpi5hvW/#AFo')
```

Otherwise, the key you really get is `PRIE7-Yf17kEnUEpi5hvW/#AFo` (assuming the variable `$oG2uS` is not defined).

Answer (score 18):

Recommend [Apache Common Codec Library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/HmacUtils.html), quite simple and easy to use.
`HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(key, string_to_sign);`

Comment: Deprecated. Use this instead now:  new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_1, key).hmacHex(inputStreamOfContent);

Answer (score 11):

The other answers pointing out HmacUtils from Apache commons have been deprecated by now. Apache commons now recommends using:

`new HmacUtils(HmacAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA_1, key).hmacHex(string_to_sign)`

Answer (score 7):

Any $ symbol in double quotes ("") is regarded as a a variable in PHP. You can avoid the error by using either single quotes as pointed out by the previous commenter or you can escape the dollar sign as below

```
hash_hmac("sha1", "helloworld", "PRIE7\$oG2uS-Yf17kEnUEpi5hvW/#AFo")
```

Notice $ is now \$

Answer (score 2):

In **Java**, and using **maven**:

Add the below dependency into the `pom.xml`:

```
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

and then try to sign it using this

```
HmacUtils.hmacSha1Hex(key, string_to_sign);
```

Comment: hmacSha1Hex is deprecated please update your answer